# Using ios6 constraints with iAd

Tags: ios6, iad, autolayout

I would like to use constraints to layout my view...
It should look like this :

In Portrait mode :
[image]

In Landscape mode:
[image]

My code so far is for constraint:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[profilHeader]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(profilHeader)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_ad]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_ad)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_tableView]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_tableView)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[profilHeader(100)][_ad(50)][_tableView]-0-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(profilHeader, _ad, _tableView)]];
```

If I do not put the (50) aside of _ad, the _tableView will be over it.

and of course, with the (50) aside of _ad, when to landscape, it won't move up the tableView 18px higher (since the Ad will then be 480x32)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the height of the "ad" when the orientation changes:

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints{
  [super updateViewConstraints];

  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_profilHeader]|"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_profilHeader)]];
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_ad]|"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_ad)]];
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_tableView]|"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_tableView)]];
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_profilHeader(100)][_ad][_tableView]-0-|"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_profilHeader, _ad, _tableView)]];

  //remove the existing constraint
  [self.view removeConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
  //set the height according to orientation
  if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
    self.heightConstraint=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_ad attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:0 toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1.0 constant:50];
  }
  //landscape
  else{
    self.heightConstraint=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_ad attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:0 toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1.0 constant:32];
  }
  [self.view addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
}
```